# How to connect to oracle database using spring boot

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, driver

I'm working with Spring Boot application and trying to access an Oracle database. Although it was successfully built, it gives the error below when I am trying to deploy in Kubernetes.

I changed the `application.properties` file and `pom.xml` file with below configurations:

**Application.yml**

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP>:1521:orcl
 spring.datasource.username=<username>
 spring.datasource.password=<password>
 spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

**POM file**

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

**Exception**

> ```
> ***************************
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
> ***************************
>  Description:
>  Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:
>      Property: driverclassname
>     Value: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
>     Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
>     Reason: Failed to load driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver in either of 
>             HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
>  Action:
>  Update your application's configuration
> ```

Comment: You need the OJDBC driver

Comment: Check my answer on `spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` it should be `driver.class-name`

Comment: @Dhanushka - If the issue fixed, please select correct answer. It might be useful for others. Cheers

Answer (score 8):

Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

application.yml file :

```
# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver.class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

**Note** : **driver.class-name**

Sometimes you may need to add `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` to application.yml file (for Oracle 10).

Answer (score 4):

Add below dependency and repository in the pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>codelds</id>
        <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
    </repository>
   </repositories>
```

Also add the following properties in the application.properties

```
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe(SID)
    spring.datasource.username=system
    spring.datasource.password=pw
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the db driver in the file `Application.yml` to

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.**driver**.OracleDriver or spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Comment: Another inconsistency? spring.datasource.driver.class-name v/s spring.datasource.driver-class-name

Comment: Requests for clarification or further information from OP should go in a comment, not an answer. Please only post an answer if it actually answers the question.

Comment: By the way, I found the answers to my questions:use spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver for >Oracle 9i (no **driver** needed) However, if I unpack the ojdbc6.jar I see both classes there. And the correct attribute to use is spring.datasource.driver-class-name

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Oracle JDBC driver jar file and add it into your classpath in order for your application to load `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` class.

Driver can be downloaded from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-10201-088211.html).

Comment: I already tried it in InteliJ. It successfully build it in IDE. But when I try to deploy it in kubernetes, it gives the error. please help

Comment: Are you creating a fat jar? If yes then you can include driver jar explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the [SpringBoot app](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/tree/master/java/jdbc/SpringBootApp/src) example helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle DB,

Maven settings:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Properties settings:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.10.12:1521/orcl11
spring.datasource.username=[username]
spring.datasource.password=[password]
```

Don't use

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

- You just need to add these two dependencies in your `pom.xml` file and it will work fine.

  ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
       <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this configuration in Application.properties.**

```
 spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

#Using SID
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL
spring.datasource.username=SYSTEM   
spring.datasource.password=SYSTEM
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#hibernate configs
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

Caution:

1. org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect has been deprecated.
2. You need to check  { jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL} if the last part of this DATABASE URL is {ORCL} OR {XE}. SEE THE ATTACHED SCREENSHOT.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsVqG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I used `implementation 'com.oracle:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2.0` gradle dependency.

Added below in the application.properties.

```
#hibernate configs
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

# database details
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<host>:<port>/<database>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driver.class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

You can use different `OracleDialect` if its not working for you.

For me above code is working without any issue.